# MySQL MAX CONNECTIONS PER HOUR optimal value

Tags: php, mysql

My project is a website with dynamic pages.

Every time a user runs a query (which returns results displayed in a table generated by PHP) I connect to the database, query it and then disconnect immediately.

If I estimate the maximum value of queries/hour my user can make, the result may be 60 mins x 5 queries/min = 300 queries/hour.

I also have some additional queries generated by JavaScript, I can add an extra 100 per hour for those.

So considering the above, my MAX CONNECTIONS... should be 400. Of course, this is probably a maximum value.

Is this correct ? Can you tell me what a "usual" value is ?

EDIT: I have no experience at all on this matter, I'm not a dbA. I thought that limiting these numbers per account is good security policy.

My connection code is:

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password, "Database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   $err_message = 'Unable to connect to DB'.PHP_EOL.mysqli_connect_error();
   ...
   }
```

Comment: This totally depends on your environment but I don't see a reason to set a lower limit to this. Take your calculations and multiply by 100 or even 1000. I wouldn't suggest putting a value lower than 100,000 queries per hour.

Comment: What makes you think the mysql setting is the max amount *per hour*? As far as I can see it's **max simultaneous client connections** allowed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections

Comment: try to make the database connection persistence

Comment: @rednaw Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html

Comment: @LStarky Why do you think it is a LOWER limit. See my link to the official documentation in the comment above. Excerpt: _As the server runs, it counts the number of times each account uses resources. If an account reaches its limit on number of connections within the last hour, the server rejects further connections for the account until that hour is up_

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you [edit] your question to tell us whether you'r using `PDO` or `mysqli_` application programmer classes to connect to php. Why? connection pooling on the php side of your setup dominates the situation.

Comment: What is your purpose for limiting this?  If you're worried about server resources, you don't need to be.  MySQL is extremely efficient and can manage TRILLIONS of queries per hour.  Why set a low limit that might cause you problems later?  I don't see much of a reason at all to set this value at all, or certainly not to anything less than what your wildest imagination could imagine your website growing to.

Comment: It is true that there is the default account which will be used by multiple users, so I should multiply my figure above with some number of average users.

Comment: Like other people before me said - your question lacks info about environment. For example, if you use `php-fpm` and persistent connections, then `php-fpm` can create a pool that it maintains and number of connection doesn't exceed the number of its child processes (and this number is usually equal to number of CPU cores). There's too much missing info here, and I suspect you don't have an app that's overly big. Do you have a problem with MySQL or is this question purely from curiosity POV?

Comment: @N.B. As I said in my edit, I wanted to prevent possible security issues if I set those values incorrectly - either too high or too low.

Comment: There are no security issues related to those values. You first have to know what security issues you might have before you start thinking whether number of connections might impose a security threat. The two aren't related, it seems you're making up a problem where it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not limit MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR, MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR, or any of that stuff when you `GRANT` access to your php web application.  Nothing good can come of it. If your php app hits those limits it will start throwing nasty obscure error messages to your users. That stuff is not for web applications. It is there for corporate style applications where adam, barney, and charlie each have their own username and password on the MySQL server.

Web server machines usually have just one, or maybe two, username/password combinations used on behalf of all users.  It's bad security practice to create accounts on the MySQL server to which users know the passwords.

As for an overall maximum number of connections, it depends on the size of your MySQL server machine and the number of web server machines serving your web app.  [`mysqli_` has persistent connections built in](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php), so the connections get re-used.   When the connections run out, usually php requests get queued up.

100 connections per web server machine is probably OK, unless your web server machines are huge quad-core monsters with 16g of memory each.

Comment: By the way, the load computations you did in your question are sound. That kind of computation will come up again for you when you're ready to scale out this application.

Comment: My website will be hosted, so I guess the servers will have no problem with the connections number. My reason for this question was security. I am completely new to this - this being the reason of me asking "Is this (my thinking, that is) correct ?". Thanks for all your answers and comments.

Comment: Don't let your hosting provider limit MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR, etc. !!  They probably won't try, but if they do, fire them and get another provider. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all...**

What is your purpose for limiting this? If you're worried about server resources, you don't need to be. MySQL is extremely efficient and can manage TRILLIONS of queries per hour. Why set a low limit that might cause you problems later? I don't see much of a reason at all to set this value at all, or certainly not to anything less than what your wildest imagination could imagine your website growing to.  So, if you decide to specify this, make sure it's a big number like 100,000.

**Secondly...**

Maybe you're asking because you're in the process of creating user accounts.  However, the parameters specified here are *optional* and in most cases probably not much of a concern.  I would suggest that unless there is a specific problem, you just don't specify these options.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html

Comment: Yes, I am creating accounts today - this website is developed solely by me and for a project of mine, so I have nobody else to ask.